# Windows 10 desktop closes command line if left overnight

Tags: windows-10, command-line, sleep, logoff

I've been leaving important things running overnight on command line which are time critical for me and when I come back they are rarely still running. The command line window isn't even open. This morning it was logged out and when i logged back it it wasn't there. Even if it was logged out it shouldn't have closed it right? I have gone to System>Accounts>Sign-in Options and selected never for when it should require log in, but when i go back on the screen that box turns back to blank. I don't know if this is a text formatting issue or not.

Basically I find this unacceptable from Windows and really cant afford it to happen again.

Also When I go into power option when to sleep and when to turn off display are both set to never.

Any life savers out there?

Note. I have checked the event logs and found this:

> The process C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe (DESKTOP-#######) has initiated the restart of computer DESKTOP-####### on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
>    Reason Code: 0x80020010
>    Shut-down Type: restart
>    Comment:

My restart options looks a bit different and on isn't clickable.: 
[image]

Comment: If your system did a forced restart for whatever reason then any running processed will be terminated. Look in the event logs to see what happened overnight.

Comment: "This morning it was logged out and when i logged back it it wasn't there."  According to `systeminfo` when was the last time the system was booted?  Was it last night?  Is this your personal computer, or does it belong to your work?  I ask because this sounds like group policy and/or Windows Updates to me.

Comment: Check what your "active hours" are.  If there is an update to windows 10 pending, it will automatically install the update and restart the computer outside of what is set in active hours.  Assuming this is set to the day, the computer may restart at night or early morning, causing the lock screen, requiring you to sign in again, and stopping all running processes.

Comment: It is my own personal desktop. I have updated the comment with more info.

Comment: How do I see what my 'active hours' are

Comment: Check this link: http://www.windowscentral.com/how-configure-active-hours-avoid-windows-10-sudden-restarts-during-updates If you are on the creators update it might be slightly different.

Comment: My restart options looks a bit different and on isn't clickable. http://puu.sh/vMVWI/7b383e560c.png
Absolutely not okay windows keeps you to a set 'work time' duration in active hours

Comment: Yea that Restart option will be greyed out until there is a pending update, then you can set it to restart at a specific time. Microsoft has gotten very aggressive with forcing updates.  To stop them completely you would have to do what LPChip said in his answer, just be sure to keep on top of your updates so you aren't vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

So according to the information you posted, Windows restarted your computer due to installing Windows Updates.

Do note that since the Creators update, Windows tends to try and reopen any program that was still running. It doesn't fully restore everything, but before this update, it would restore nothing, so its a great start.

Given that you don't want windows updates to restart your computer, make sure you use active hours and when windows announces it will restart the computer, go to the windows update settings and choose to plan the restart (This option is grayed out if there are no planned restarts). This way, you can delay it up to a week, but in the next days, you can again plan it, and keep delaying it.

If that is not an option, consider disabling the Windows Update service. This way, your computer will be at risk if you don't do windows updates yourself, but at least your computer will not reboot when you don't want to either.

Do note, that just stopping the windows update is not enough. You also have to edit the service, and set its startup type to disabled.

Comment: You can also schedule the restart for a specific time.

Comment: You can only schedule a time if there is a pending update to be installed obviously.

Comment: @Ramhound Read the comments on OP and see what you mean. I've edited my post. tnx. :)